# iOS : Is it possible to read/clear notification of all apps installed in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, launcher, utility

1. Is it possible to read push notifications(with App name & content) of all application installed in iPhone/iPad ?
2. Also let us know if we can delete specific notifications / all notifications from notification center.
3. Will apple approve such applications ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. 
Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html).